# Area of a region in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting, regions

I've plotted two polar curves.

```
PolarPlot[{3 Sin[t], 1 + Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}]
```

[image]

I'd like to shade the region that lies inside the circle but outside of the cardioid. Then I'd like to find the area of the shaded region using Mathematica's Area command.

Is this possible using polar coordinates? Can someone share some suggestions?

**Update:** Thanks for posting some old questions I asked. Couldn't find them. Here is what I finally came up with:

```
Clear[r, t]
Show[
  PolarPlot[{3 Sin[t], 1 + Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}],
  ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, π/6, 5 π/6}, {r, 1 + Sin[t], 3 Sin[t]}]]
```

[image]

Now, rather than using ImplicitRegion, I used:

```
Area[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, π/6, 5 π/6}, {r, 1 + Sin[t], 3 Sin[t]}]
```

Which returns an exact answer of $\pi$. Here is the timing.

```
Area[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, π/6, 5 π/6}, {r, 1 + Sin[t], 3 Sin[t]}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.722002, π}

Comment: possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5087/9490

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114760/integrate-to-calculate-enclosed-area

Comment: Thanks to everyone for pointing out some old posts of mine. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to use `ImplicitRegion` to represent the disk and cardioid regions by using your formulas as the maximum radius in polar coordinates and converting this to a cartesian representation that is easier to use with `ImplicitRegion`. Then we can get your desired region as the `RegionDifference` and plot it via `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
tocartesian = {t -> ArcTan[x, y], r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}
diskregion = ImplicitRegion[r < (3 Sin[t]) /. tocartesian // Simplify, {x, y}]
cardioidregion = ImplicitRegion[r < (1 + Sin[t]) /. tocartesian // Simplify, {x, y}]
crescentregion = RegionDifference[diskregion, cardioidregion]
DiscretizeRegion[crescentregion, PrecisionGoal->6]
RegionMeasure[%]
```

[image: Discretized crescent shaped region]

```
(* Out[1]= 3.14159 *)
```

The area seems to be `Pi`. In theory we should be able to verify this symbolically with

```
RegionMeasure[crescentregion]
```

but Mathematica seems to take a bit longer to solve the integral for this region (i.e. it didn't finish on my machine after a few minutes).

Comment: +1 - you could also use your replacement rule to transform the difference region, and use `reg = r < (3 Sin[t]) && r > (1 + Sin[t]) /. tocartesian;
{RegionPlot[reg, {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, 1/2, 3}],
DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y}]}`

Comment: @JasonB. Yeah, i was thinking the same, and trying out the same thing at the moment actually :) The thing that i'm trying to figure out his how to get the area of the region. It's easy and fast for the discretized version with `RegionMeasure`, but the implicit version seems to set off a nontrivial integral computation in Mathematica and doesn't seem to finish...

Comment: I did notice that `Area[ ImplicitRegion[...` was taking a **long** time, so I also didn't see a better way to get the area.

Answer (score 3):

The same as Thies Heidecke calculated it, only with other procedures.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
    r < 3 Sin[φ] && r > 1 + Sin[φ], {r, φ} -> {x, y}], {x, y}];
Area@DiscretizeRegion[reg, PrecisionGoal -> 6]

3.14159
```

Addition

Another way with area = 1/2 Integrate[r^2(φ) dφ]:

```
r1 = 1 + Sin[φ];
r2 = 3 Sin[φ];
{φ1, φ2} = φ /. Solve[r1 == r2, φ] /. C[1] -> 0
{π/6, (5 π)/6}

area = 1/2 Integrate[r2^2 - r1^2, {φ, φ1, φ2}] //AbsoluteTiming
{0.156459, π}
```